# Selenium WebDriver Java - org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog for Basic Authentication Window in IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, basic-authentication, selenium-webdriver, autoit

I am using Java, Selenium-WebDriver (2.25) , Maven, JUnit to Develop tests for one of the website.

The tests are working fine for [Firefox and Chrome]. The same tests are not working for IE.

Scenario: User registers to a page, get redirected from Domain A to Domain B. Domain B is Basic Authenticated. I am handling it using autoIT[as I do have to run them in windows env. only].

Flow : 
Register Click i.e. submit the form 
it will go to the next page. will ask for username and password. 
Before autoit can work it gives the exception of unhandled alert.

I hope someone can help me.

It is giving me exception i.e. 
"org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present"

The problem I think is I am not handling the alert, but why only in IE it is recognized as part of the page, not in FF and Chrome [for them autoIT solution is working perfectly].

Comment: As an experiment, I would try adding the site as a trusted site in your IE settings and then rerun the test and see if there is a difference.